# How to verify ID token from AAD, and then call user info

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, jwt

I am trying to log in from Azure Active Directory, and do get a token in return. How do I now verify said token and log in?
I am also trying to get access_token and get userinfo, but get an error when adding token to response_type.

My client code is:

```
export function AzureLogin(){
  useEffect(async  () => {
    const { authorization_endpoint } = await fetchJSON(
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    );

    const parameters = {
      client_id: "my client id",
      response_type: "id_token (id_token%20token when trying to get access_token)",
      scope: "openid",
      nonce: "123",
      redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/login/azure/callback"
    }

    window.location.href =
        authorization_endpoint + "?" + new URLSearchParams(parameters)
  }, [])
}

export function AzureCallback(){
  useEffect(async () => {
    const { id_token } = Object.fromEntries(
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.substring(1))
    );

    await fetch("/api/login/azure", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id_token }),
    })
  })
}
```

And my server code is:

```
router.post("/azure", async (req, res) => {
        const { id_token } = req.body;

        res.cookie("id_token", id_token, {signed: true, maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000});

          const {userinfo_endpoint} = await fetchJSON(
              "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
          );

          const userinfo = await fetchJSON(userinfo_endpoint, {
              headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${id_token}`,
              },
          })

      console.log(userinfo)

          const name = userinfo.name;
          const id = userinfo.sub;
          const email = userinfo.email;
          const picture = userinfo.picture;

          db stuff

        res.sendStatus(200);
      })
```

Comment: UPDATE: managed to get the access_token by itself, but not the Id token, what exactly is the id token used for then if I do not need it for getting user profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in your comment.

The purpose of the ID-token is to tell the client details about how the user authenticated. It is typically only used to create the local "session" in the client and then thrown away.

The ID-token typically have a very short lifetime (like 5 minutes in some setups) and it is not supposed to be sent to external services/APIs.

The client is not supposed to look inside the access-token and it doesn't even need to validate it. It is the job of the API that later receives the token to validate the signature of the access-token against the public signing key in AzureAD.

Comment: So in theory I should only set access token and call userinfo after an ID-token is found and verified in the request?

Comment: Sort of yes, but there are libraries that handle most of this work for you, so you don't need to go into the details.